# How to get the return value of the start rule

Tags: bison, yacc

How to get the 'return' value (`$$` variable) of the start rule of a grammar with Yacc/Bison?

`yyparse` return the error code of the parser.

Answer (score 8):

The easiest solution is to store the value in an additional argument to `yyparse`. Normally you will store this value in the action for your start rule; sometimes it is useful to define an extra start non-terminal with a unit production to hold the action.

If you're using bison, you can use the [`%parse-param`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#index-_0025parse_002dparam) directive to define the extra argument, and then you just need to call `yyparse` with the address of the variable into which the result should be stored.

You still need to check the return value from `yyparse`; if it doesn't indicate success, then the value returned through the out parameter will not be correct.